# How to make xml to csv parsing/conversion faster?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, csv

I'm currently using the snippet below to convert xml data(not well formed) to .CSV format after doing some processing in between. It only converts those elements in the xml data that contain a integer from the list testList (`List<int> testList`). It only converts and writes to the file once that match has been made. I need to use this algorithm for files that are several GB's in size. Currently it processes a 1 Gb file in ~7.5 minutes. Can someone suggest any changes that I could make to improve performance? I've fixed everything I could but it won't get any faster. Any help will be appreciated!

Note: `Message.TryParse` is an external parsing method that I have to use and can't exclude or change. 
Note: `StreamElements` is just a customized Xmlreader that improves performance.

```
foreach (var element in StreamElements(p, "XML"))
                {
                    string joined = string.Concat(element.ToString().Split().Take(3)) + string.Join(" ", element.
                        ToString().Split().Skip(3));
                    List<string> listX = new List<string>();
                    listX.Add(joined.ToString());
                    Message msg = null;
                    if (Message.TryParse(joined.ToString(), out msg))
                    {
                        var values = element.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>()
                        .Select(v => Regex.Replace(v.Value, "\\s+", " "));

                        foreach (var val in values)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < testList.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (val.ToString().Contains("," + testList[i].ToString() + ","))
                                {
                                    var line = string.Join(",", values);
                                    sss.WriteLine(line);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Comment: @cubrr what? how? where?

Comment: The main `foreach` loop. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @cubrr Parallel.ForEach will help me if multiple files are being processed together but don't think it can make this algorithm better

Comment: Be careful about introducing parallelism. Will this program still be correct if the `WriteLine` calls are made in a different order?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Won't be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing some things you could probably improve:

- You're calling `.ToString()` on `joined` a couple of times, when `joined` is already a string.
- You may be able to speed up your regex replace by compiling your regex first, outside of the loop.
- You're iterating over `values` multiple times, and each time it has to re-evaluate the LINQ that makes up the definition for `values`. Try using `.ToList()` before saving the result of that LINQ statement into `values`.

But before focusing on stuff like this, you really need to identify what's taking the time in your code. My guess is that it's almost all spent in these two places:

1. Reading from the XML stream
2. Writing to `sss`

If I'm right, then anything else you focus on is going to be premature optimization. Spend some time testing what happens if you comment out various parts of your `for` loop, to see where all the time is being spent.

Comment: element is a XElement, so I have to call .toString() over there and the regex, yes. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @sparta93: I didn't say anything about `element`--I'm talking about `joined`

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. And where exactly should I use .ToList()? a little confused.

Comment: `var values = element.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().toList().Select(v => Regex.Replace(v.Value, "\\s+", " "));`  Like this?

Comment: @sparta93: `var values = element.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().Select(v => Regex.Replace(v.Value, "\\s+", " ")).ToList();`. That way, when you pass `values` into `string.Join()`, it doesn't have to redo the Regex.Replace.